# Every graph has a core

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm currently going through Godsil/Royle's chapter about graph homomorphisms and using the following definitions I struggle to follow through the proof of the existence of a core of a graph.

> A graph $X$ is a **core** if every homomorphism $f$ from $X$ to itself is a bijection.
>
> A subgraph $Y$ is a **core** of $X$ if $Y$ is a core and there exists a homomorphism from $X$ to $Y$.

Let $X$ be a finite graph. Since $id_X: V(X) \to V(X), v \mapsto v$ is a homomorphism the family of subgraphs from $X$ to which $X$ has a homomorphism is finite and not empty. Hence, there exists a minimal subgraph $Y$ with respect to inclusion.

Why is $Y$ a core of $X$? It is clear that there exists a homomorphism $X \to Y$ but why is every endomorphism of $Y$ an isomorphism?

Comment: Isn't a minimal subgraph just a vertex?

Comment: @Berci: not necessarily, because it has to be the result of a homomorphism, so the vertex would have to have a loop if $X$ is nontrivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shown that there exists a $Y$ which is a minimal subgraph of $X$ such that there exists a homomorphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Now, suppose that there exists a homomorphism $g:Y\rightarrow Y$ which is not a bijection. This means that $g(Y)$ has less vertices than $Y$. However, homomorphisms are closed under composition, so that $f\circ g$ is a homomorphism from $X$ to $g(Y)$. But $Y$ was minimal in the above sense, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this makes perfect sense to me. One thing though, you're talking about $g \circ f$ being a homomorphism from $X$ to $g(Y)$, right?

Comment: @PeterMcCoy yep corrected. Thanks!